# Unable to make table rows clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table as shown in the snippet below:

```css
#myTable {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable th {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#myTable td {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#myTable tr {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr td a {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

#myTable tr.header {
 background-color: #5585cc;
 color: white;
}

#myTable tr:hover {
 background-color: #8FB7E7;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr class="header">
   <th style="width: 25%;">Name on Card</th>
   <th style="width: 18%;">Card Type</th>
   <th style="width: 21%;">Card Number</th>
   <th style="width: 18%;">Expiration</th>
   <th style="width: 18%;">Status</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="rClickable">
   <td>Richard Weld</td>
   <td>VISA</td>
   <td>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0512</td>
   <td>03/22</td>
   <td>ACTIVE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rClickable">
   <td>Timothy J McGinley</td>
   <td>VISA</td>
   <td>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2475</td>
   <td>12/17</td>
   <td>ACTIVE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rClickable">
   <td>Avis Budget Group</td>
   <td>VISA</td>
   <td>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5324</td>
   <td>05/21</td>
   <td>INACTIVE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rClickable">
   <td>Donna Fleetwood</td>
   <td>VISA</td>
   <td>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-9985</td>
   <td>07/19</td>
   <td>ACTIVE</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make the rows clickable. I tried many things like:

```
<tr onclick="javascript:window.location.assign('/epayui/app/payments/enterPayment');">
```

I have tried jquery('rClickable' is the class of each ro):

```
    $(".rClickable").click(function(){
    window.location.assign = "/epayui/app/payments/enterProfilePayment";
    });
```

Another version

```
$("#rClickable").on("click","tr",function(){
        window.location.assign = "/epayui/app/payments/enterProfilePayment";
    });
```

Nothing of these worked for me. I also have a `$(document).ready();` function, but there is nothing in there as of now. I have planned to use it for something, so I can not remove it.

I don't want to use bootstrap. Only javascript or jquery.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well is the JS to add the click event inside of the document ready?

Comment: The first two examples should work fine. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: No. Click events are outside the ready function. @epascarello

Comment: well there is your problem.... You are probably binding events to elements that do not exist yet

Comment: https://datatables.net/ Since you are using jQ already, have you thought about this. It simplifies working with tables a lot.

Comment: `location.assign(url);` <---- and assign is a method....

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan console shows like : "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function" and "Uncaught TypeError: document.location.href is not a function at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick"

Comment: The first error means that `$` does not refer to jQuery, or you're using an ***ancient*** version of jQuery which needs to be upgraded ASAP. Have you got other libraries included in the page?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ancient version of jQuery. Pre `on`

Comment: Yep, just had the same thought. Didn't cross my mind at first. I upvoted your answer as it seems the most likely issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo're using a *very* old version of jQuery in your snippet - before the function `on` existed.

You can use `click` to achieve your requirement as shown below.

```js
$(function(){
   $('.rClickable').click(function(){
       console.log("You clicked", $('td:first',this).text());
   });
});
```

```css
#myTable {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable th {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#myTable td {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#myTable tr {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr td a {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

#myTable tr.header {
 background-color: #5585cc;
 color: white;
}

#myTable tr:hover {
 background-color: #8FB7E7;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr class="header">
   <th style="width: 25%;">Name on Card</th>
   <th style="width: 18%;">Card Type</th>
   <th style="width: 21%;">Card Number</th>
   <th style="width: 18%;">Expiration</th>
   <th style="width: 18%;">Status</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="rClickable">
   <td>Richard Weld</td>
   <td>VISA</td>
   <td>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0512</td>
   <td>03/22</td>
   <td>ACTIVE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rClickable">
   <td>Timothy J McGinley</td>
   <td>VISA</td>
   <td>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2475</td>
   <td>12/17</td>
   <td>ACTIVE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rClickable">
   <td>Avis Budget Group</td>
   <td>VISA</td>
   <td>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5324</td>
   <td>05/21</td>
   <td>INACTIVE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rClickable">
   <td>Donna Fleetwood</td>
   <td>VISA</td>
   <td>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-9985</td>
   <td>07/19</td>
   <td>ACTIVE</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Its nice. Thanks. Can you also tell me how to redirect to someother url on click?

Comment: @Waquar as you were. [`location.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) works. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location